# Can't delete 'cloud calendar' from my iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1.2 and I cannot delete a cloud calendar.  When I edit and go to the calendar all I get is the name of the calendar and the color that represents it.  No delete button at the bottom.  In fact, nothing below the colors.  Has anyone had this issue and are there any solutions short of a reset?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst the device model and iOS version are useful information, the title to your question should be as descriptive as possible regarding what the *problem* is that you are facing. I've edited the title to explain what I believe the actual problem is, but feel free to edit further.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribed Calendar can't be deleted directly from the Calendar app.

Go to Settings → Mail, Contacts, Calendars and you can unsubscribe from it.

Sometimes subscribed calendars on OS X can't be deleted on iOS.

Comment: I attempted the Mail, Contacts, Calendars solution and I found where I have one subscribed calendar and I am actually using that one.  The one I'm trying to remove says subscribed but doesn't show up there.  In fact the only place it shows up is in the calendars tab within the open app. It doesn't show up on my iPad or MacBook Pro, just on the iPhone so I don't know the source to attempt deleting at that point.

Comment: Dose this subscribed Calendar belongs to iCloud group?